# Is there a way to vectorize this matlab for loop?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, compiler-optimization

```
for i = 2:N
    A(i,i-1:i+1) = [1, -2, 1];
end
```

Hello, matlab is telling me that this code can be faster by using spalloc for the matrix A (which I have) but also by vectorizing this for loop. I've tried to use the following:

```
i = 2:N
A(i, i-1:i+1)
```

but the result obviously turned out to be not what I want.

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: MATLAB told you that you should vectorize the loop? I've never seen such a message! This one is not trivial to vectorize, especially if you want a sparse matrix. But if you are trying to implement a convolution by multiplying with such a matrix, then `conv` will be a much better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to get a second-order difference operator, except your loop winds up missing the first row and including an extra column.  The normal (sparse) difference operator is generated like this:

```matlab
N = 10;
v = ones(N, 1);
A = spdiags([v -2*v v], [-1 0 1], N, N);
full(A)  % for display only
```

You'll see:

```
ans =
    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2
```

If that's not quite what you want (e.g., you really don't want the first row), then it's probably faster to generate it as above and then fix it up.